# ipython console2 no module named Ipython

Tags: python, path, console, ipython

I've been using ipython notebook with console2 for a while now and recently installed a different version of python and now my console is giving me an error saying "No module named IPython". I think the path has been changed or something, but I don't know how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to install ipython again for your new python, the same as any other module.

Comment: @Wooble is that really the only way to do it? I'll try it this time, but it seems like a bad solution..

Comment: That didn't work. I uninstalled Anaconda, reinstalled it, and I am getting the same error..

Comment: Did you point your PATH to the right Python directory? (System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pulling the answer out of the comments.

Point your `PATH` system variable to the correct version of Python. This is accomplished (on Windows) by going to `System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables`. If you already have a Python directory in there, modify it to the correct, new path. Otherwise, append it to the end of the existing string. Do not remove what is already present.

Comment: Yeah, this worked for me. Thank you. I believe this is probably a repeated question, but I just didn't realize that the solution was via the environment variables. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda for python the ipython installation is on "Scripts" folder
To get the console2 running with ipython you all have to do to start cmd in silent mode by configuring a new tab in the console2 settings window on win7

here is my config for the shell:

```
cmd.exe /k C:\Anaconda\python.exe "C:\Anaconda\Scripts/ipython-script.py"
```

for the startup dir i have just defined the workspace i am using:

```
D:\python-workspace
```